# React Vite TS project that call external lib has error: "Fled to resolve module specifier"

Tags: typescript, vite

I created a react vite project, the project call external library:

```
import { SomeType } from '@packages/types/dist/esnext';
```

on development everything works well.
When I deploy the code I get the error:
`caught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@packages/types/dist/esnext". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

this is the vite config:

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 9001,
    hmr: true,
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [
        '@packages/types/dist/esnext',
      ]
    }
    },

  plugins: [
    react({
      include: ["**/*.tsx"],
    }),
    viteTsconfigPaths(),
    svgrPlugin(),
  ],
});
```

this is the vite tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "types": ["node", "vite/client"],
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    //"vite-plugin-svgr/client"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

this is the package tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist/esnext",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "test", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

how can I fix this error?
Thanks